# How to toggle class and template if in array using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

UPDATE: Almost there. Added the template to HTML. Added v-if and v-else to the button (couldn't get it to work on the template). Hard coded the example below. Trying to sus out final object path to array - for some reason `v-if="this.id == favourites.listings_id"` isn't working.

I'm building a favourites feature using vue.js. The create and delete requests both work fine. Finally what's required is to either show class favourited or notFavourited with appropriate action template create or delete depending on if the user has favourited the object or not. The users favourites array passes to the favourites component - and I've been trying to handled it that way.

I've commented out what I'm trying to achieve in the js code below.

HTML

```
<div id="app">

<listings>
</listings>

</div>

<template id="listing-template">
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="listing in listings" class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div>@{{ listing.id }}</div>

        <favourite :id="listing.id"></favourite>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<template id="favourite-template">
  <form><input class="hidden" type="input" name="_method" value="@{{ id }}" v-model="form.listings_id"></input><button v-if="this.id == 2" class="not-favourited" @click.prevent="create(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i><button v-else class="favourited" @click.prevent="delete(favourite)" :disabled="form.busy"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></form>
</template>
```

VUE.JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});

Vue.component('favourite', {
  props: ['id'],

  data: function() {
    return {
        form: new SparkForm({
            listings_id: ''
        }),
        favourited: {
          color: 'red',
          fontSize: '12px'
        },
        notFavourited: {
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: '12px'
        },
        favourites: [], listings: [],
    };
  },

  created() {
      this.getFavourites();
  },

  methods: {
    getFavourites() {
        this.$http.get('/api/favourites')
          .then(response => {
            this.favourites = response.data;
          });
        },

    // if favourite exists in favourites array
    // then give class favourited and call template delete
    // else give class notFavourited and call template create

    create() {
        Spark.post('/api/favourite', this.form)
            .then(favourite => {
            this.favourite.push(favourite);

            this.form.id = '';
            });
        },

        delete(favourite) {
            this.$http.delete('/api/favourite/' + this.id);
            this.form.id = '';

        }
      }
});

Vue.component('listings',  {
    template: '#listing-template',

    data: function() {
      return {
            listings: [],
        };
    },

    created() {
        this.getListings();
    },

    methods: {
      getListings() {
          this.$http.get('/api/listings')
            .then(response => {
              this.listings = response.data;
          });
        }
      }
});
```

EXAMPLE OBJECT IN FAVOURITES ARRAY

```
4: Object
created_at: "2016-07-22 21:14:40"
id: 81
listings_id: 1
updated_at: "2016-07-22 21:14:40"
user_id: 3
```

Comment: Have you had any success with this issue?

Comment: @gurghet still working on it and looking into JSON.stringify